# I want to pass multiple values from different div tags to another php page using Ajax code on button click function

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to pass multiple values from from different `<div>` tags to another php page(`onewaytrip_passenger_data.php`) using ajax code on button `onclick()` function. This is my ajax function:

```
<script language="javascript">
function continoue(){
    var a=$("#temp").text();
    var b=$("#sno").text();

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {  
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("sno").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","onewaytrip_passenger_data.php?count="+a+"seatno="+b,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

`#temp` and `sno` are my two different `<div>` id's these are my `<div>` tags

```
<div id="temp" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
<div id="sno" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
```

This is my button:

```
<input name="continoue" type="image" src="images/contioue.png" onclick="continoue()"/>
```

Comment: What are you trying to send? Those divs are empty. Also, your link needs an `&` (well, depending on what your php is doing): `"onewaytrip_passenger_data.php?count="+a+"&seatno="+b`

Comment: Also, if you are using jQuery to get the `var` values, why not use jQuery ajax to send?

Comment: Also, instead of doing an inline js, why not do a jQuery `click()` or `on("click")`?

Comment: i am very poor in using ajax.. so i dont know how to use jquery ajax, so please help me..

Comment: @raghuveer999 wrote it out for you (the ajax)

Comment: Ajax is not at all difficult. Just go through it once. You will enjoy writing code with ajax.

Refer the link.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery ajax function:

```
function continoue(){
    var a=$("#temp").text();
    var b=$("#sno").text();
    $.ajax({  
         type: "GET",  
         url: "onewaytrip_passenger_data.php",  
         data : {count:a, seatno:b},
         success: function (response) {
          if (response == "success" ) {
             //do something
          } else {              
              //something
          }
      },
      error: function () {
          //console.log('Error --------');
      }
     });
}
```

in PHP file after your success code is done,

just write

```
<?php echo "success"; ?>
```

for failure,

```
<?php echo "failure"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = $("#temp").html();
    var b = $("#sno").html();
    $.get("onewaytrip_passenger_data.php", {count: a, seatno: b})
            .done(function (data) {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("error");
    });
</script>
```

Please read [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) also for your reference.